# Counter Counter Knife - Punch Stab

Tags: battlefield-4

Sometime in BF4 people will punch me and knife me giving me no opportunity to counter knife, even if the `F` key is prompting to press. How do I do this when I knife people so that they cannot counter?

For reference - [Here's a Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbGJW-5O6P0) of what I mean. When you're actually in the game though, you can mash `F` to counter but it has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

You (or your victim) only gets a chance to counter the knife attack if you try it **head on** (you and your victim are facing each other).

To guarantee a kill without a counter, you have to attack from an angle (from the side, from behind, etc.).

The "magic punch" in the video happens because the opportunity to counter was missed, and not due to a specific button combination.

Comment: Exactly. Every other case can be blamed on "netcode" (although I hate that complaint) or other synchronization bugs, where the knifed player is facing in another direction than the one you see or the "player pressed F" message arrives too late at the server.